# Spatial SQL Compare all polygons in table and return which ones intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, polygon, spatial

I have a table with ~50,000 rows. Each row is a polygon. I would like to compare all the rows to see which ones are touching/intersect.

```
Select a.PolygonID, b.PolygonID, a.OGR_Geography.STIntersects(b.OGR_Geography) as Intersect
into #temp1
FROM table1 as a cross join table1 as b;

Select a.PolygonID, b.PolygonID,Intersect
WHERE Intersection = 1
```

Other than doing a `CROSS JOIN` and creating a gigantic table, what would be the best way to compare each polygon and return which other polygon it is touching/intersect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join on the Intersection

```
SELECT
    a.PolygonID,
    b.PolygonID
FROM
    table1 AS a
    INNER JOIN
    table1 as b
    ON (a.OGR_Geography.STIntersects(b.OGR_Geography) = 1);
```